# Redirect unless the URL starts with a specific string

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, https

How to configure Apache HTTP Server to redirect every request (say to HTTPS) unless the URL starts with a specific string (say /.well-known/) and serve resources from a directory if that is the case? (This case is needed for HTTP domain validation to approve TLS/SSL certificates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your configuration was like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

then it will be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DocumentRoot /http-data/
    RedirectMatch "^(?!\/specific_string\/.*$).*" "https://www.example.com$0"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then if the URL starts with "/specific_string/", it will serve files from the directory "/http-data/". For instance for "http://example.com/specific_string/index.html" will serve from directory "/http-data/specific_string/index.html".

But the any other URL like "http://example.com/other", it will redirect to "https://www.example.com/other".

Tested on Apache HTTP Server 2.4.